# PHP dom parser: How to get element count only if it comes after another element?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get a count of how many images are on an HTML page sprinkled throughout an article but I do not want to count the image if it comes before the text of the article begins. The problem is the classes are exactly the same, so I can't use that to help me, and not every article is even going to start with an image. So the HTML might look like this:

```
<img class="image-asset" src="image.jpg">
<p>First line</p>
<p>Second line</p>
<img class="image-asset" src="second_image.jpg">
<p>Third line</p>
<img class="image-asset" src="third_image.jpg">
```

In this instance, I want to only count the second and third images. Here's my code, which is successfully counting every image at the moment:

```
$photoCount = count($html->find('div.image-asset'));
```

Comment: So in this example, it's the first image you don't want to count? What part of the DOM is defining what an 'article' is?

Comment: Is the start of the text of an "article" always in a `<p>` tag?

Comment: I see some options to achieve what you want to do. However it depends on how the article is defined markup wise. So options would be to traverse the dom tree, use a callback function or to use regular expression.

Comment: Correct, the first image - if it is the first thing in the article - I do not want to count.
And yes, there will always be at least one <p> tag before the first photo I want to count.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something along these lines:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$target = $xpath->query('//img[preceding-sibling::p]');
echo count($target), PHP_EOL;
//and just to be on the safe side:
foreach ($target as $t) {
    echo $t->ownerDocument->saveHTML($t), PHP_EOL;
};
```

Output:

```
2
<img class="image-asset" src="second_image.jpg">
<img class="image-asset" src="third_image.jpg">
```